# Jquery FullCalendar Reminders

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, fullcalendar, reminders

Am using **[JQuery fullCalendar plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)** from *Adam Shaw* in my web app. I went through the documentation and found different ways of interacting with events and managing it. The place where i got stuck is **reminders**. I was not able to find anything about how can we send a reminder for a particular event.
      I want to create reminders for a particular event or events and remind the users by sending notifications. How can we achieve this? If the plug in doesn't support reminder functionality please suggest some great jquery event calendar plugins that are free and do support events .

Comment: what you mean by **send events** ? by mail, or display notification in browser ?

Comment: email as well as notification

Comment: and how it related to jquery ? (email part), for browser notifications, just pull your data time to time  from server and show reminders, calendar plugin not for that

Comment: @JavaFreak: Did you find a solution to show the reminders

Comment: @JavaFreak any luck with remainder functionality please let me know i need to know please.